# How can an image be posterized in the compositor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I tried to split an image RGB values and re-combined it with rounded values in order to reproduce the results described in this [BA Thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?244118-Cool-nodes-I-didn-t-know-about&highlight=).

But instead of a posterized image all I get is an almost black image. Why is that?

[image]

The issue was that I loaded an HDR image, with standard images it works as 3pointedit pointed out the value should be reset (I just tried several values before the screenshot was made).

Comment: The manual shows another technique http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Convertor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are replicating the setup on my BA thread http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?244118-Cool-nodes-I-didn-t-know-about

then the round value should be 0.1 not 1.0

Comment: thanks for your response. Setting the value to .1 has no influence (with my setup), the original file doesn't seem to work either. Are there any requirements regarding the image format?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/compositing/types/converter/math.html
says the Round node doesn't use the second value for anything, and you have to multiply all three color channels by the cube root of the number of colors you want in the finished image, then round them. I think you might need to divide them by the cube root afterwards.

Comment: Yes, this is the case.